# Iterate over nested arrays on object values?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This is the object:

```
const b = {1: [[0, 'a'], [0, 'b'], [0, 'c']], 2: [[1, 'a'], [1, 'b']], 3: [[2, 'a'], [2, 'b']]}
```

It has been sorted with bucket sort.

I need to create a sub array with two arrays, i.e.: `{ 1: [[[0, 'a'], [0, 'b']], [[0, 'c']]]`

In order to do that I must iterate over the value.

Is there anyway to do it in linear time complexity?

My initial thoughts were to remove the value from the key, work on it on a separate loop and re-insert.

Comment: Does it matter that these arrays are inside an object? Do you need to chunk all arrays in the object, or only a single one (`b[1]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `Object.entries` like the following:

```js
var b = {1: [[0, 'a'], [0, 'b'], [0, 'c']], 2: [[1, 'a'], [1, 'b']], 3: [[2, 'a'], [2, 'b']]};
var result = {};
Object.entries(b).forEach(item => {
    result[item[0]] = [item[1]];
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's a little more complex than that, the values must be grouped into maximum of two, example: `[[[0, 'a'], [0, 'b']], [[0, 'c']]]`

Comment: @Madd World have you found a solution?